# Proof that a particular subgroup is proper

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, pro-p-groups

I've been stuck on this for a long time ... I'm reading a textbook which simply states "this subgroup is proper" but it doesn't make sense to me.

Context: I have a pro-$p$ group $G$, which just means that for every open normal subgroup $N$, the quotient $G/N$ is a finite $p$-group. I want to prove the converse: if $N$ has finite index then $N$ is open. If it helps, I also know that $G$ is compact Hausdorff.

So let $m=[G:N]$ be finite. I have two lemmas:

- **Fact #1:** $G^p[G,G]$ is open (hard to prove, but let's take it for granted).
- **Fact #2:** $[G:N]$ must be a power of $p$.

By Fact #1, the subgroup $G':=G^p[G,G]N$ must be open in $G$. That makes sense to me. Now the author simply says "by Fact #2, we have $G'\subsetneq G$. If we have this we're done: then $[G':N]<m$ so $N$ is open in $G'$ by induction, which implies it's open in $G$.

But I don't understand that remark. All we know is that $N\subseteq G'\subseteq G$, and $G/N$ is a finite $p$-group. Why does that imply $G'\subsetneq G$? There's something like $$[G:N]=[G:G'][G':N]$$ but it's totally possible that $[G:G']=1$, so this wouldn't help. Would it?

For reference, this is the proof of Proposition 1.19 in *Analytic Pro-$p$ Groups* by Dixon et al.

Comment: Is the trick not going to be to go $\frac{G}{G^{\prime}N}\cong\frac{G/N}{G^{\prime}N/N}$ and apply some finite $p$-group theory to prove that this is not trivial? As by the Burnside Basis Theorem, if $H$ has prime-power order then $\operatorname{Frat}(H)=H^p[H, H]$, so $G^{\prime}$ corresponds, in some sense, to the Fratinni subgroup.